# MapReduce. Não executa a função Reduce corretamente

Tags: java, hadoop

Olá. Estou enfrentando dificuldades para trabalhar com MapReduce. Sempre que executo a aplicação não consigo resultado, pois aparentemente a função Map executa, porém a função Reduce permanece em 0%.

Quando vou verificar os arquivos que foram gerados no servidor que o hadoop está instalado, o Input esta perfeito, em .txt como definido, porém o reduce gera uma pasta com o nome do arquivo que eu defini (nome_do_arquivo.txt), dentro dessa pasta está presente uma pasta de logs e o arquivo "part-00000", o qual está vazio.

Oque devo fazer para conseguir obter o resultado da operação?

Segue o driver para conectar a aplicação ao Hadoop:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Olá");
    ControleBD conBD = new ControleBD();
    ControleArq conAR = new ControleArq();
    conAR.gravar(conBD.pesquisa());


    JobConf conf = new JobConf(Principal.class); // Definimos qual classe o job tomará como principal
    conf.setJobName("TestePrincipal"); //Nome do job que irá executar na maquina virtual

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("/user/hadoop-user/input/DadosBancarios.txt")); // Definimos o arquivo de entrada
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("/user/hadoop-user/output/saidaDadosBancarios.txt")); // Definimos o arquivo de saida
    conf.setMapperClass(ClasseMapper.class); // configuramos a classe do mapper
    conf.setReducerClass(ClasseReducer.class); // configuramos a classe do reducer
    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class); // definimos o tipo de saida esperada para as operações de map e reduce, nesse caso Texto
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); // definimos o tipo de saida esperada para as operações de map e reduce, nesse caso inteiros
    JobClient.runJob(conf); // Executa o Job com as configurações passadas



}
```

Segue a classe Mapper:

```
public class ClasseMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void map(LongWritable chave, Text valor,OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)throws IOException {

String linha = valor.toString();
System.out.println(linha);
String ano = "";
int valorIndice = 0;

    if(linha.contains("year:")){
      String[] divisor = linha.split(":");
      ano = divisor[1];
    }
if(linha.contains("value:")){
    String[] divisor = linha.split(":");
    valorIndice = Integer.parseInt(divisor[1]);
}
output.collect(new Text(ano), new IntWritable(valorIndice));
}
}
```

Segue a classe do Reducer:

```
public class ClasseReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

public void reduce(Text chave, Iterator<IntWritable> valor, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)throws IOException {

int maxValue = 99999999;

while (valor.hasNext()) {
   maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, valor.next().get());
   }
output.collect(chave, new IntWritable(maxValue));
   }
}
```

Segue o log gerado pelo Eclipse-Plugin:

> 15/09/17 17:13:37 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
>
> > 15/09/17 17:13:38 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:38 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201509170444_0002
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:40 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:48 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201509170444_0002
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 16
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File Systems
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS bytes read=152753
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS bytes written=10
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Local bytes read=44044
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Local bytes written=88160
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=1
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=2
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=2
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=1
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=6240
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=1
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=31200
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input bytes=149856
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=6240
> >
> > 15/09/17 17:13:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=6240

Ps: Não estou utilizando o Hadoop diretamente no meu computador, ele está sendo executado em uma máquina virtual (  https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/)

Grato

Rafael Muniz